# How to succeed real-time detection on multiple images on desktop screen [Python, tkinter,pyautogui]

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, tkinter, pyautogui

new to programming, new member on stackoverflow community. for the purrpose of this code, i have been reading topics from here, tutorials about processes used etc.

my project is about a 4-player online card game (tichu), where i need to count the cards that are played in real time (total cards 56).So i make a window displaying the available cards (tkinter). im using a small part of every card (12x24 pixel) to match to the desktop (where the game is played). Program scans for every card shown onscreen, and if it finds, it replaces with darker icon on GUI. when reset button is shown inside the game, the GUI resets(pyautogui). The problem here is that the scanning and thus the refreshing of the GUI is really slow, and misses many cards (cause of next player's move). i want the program to multiscan for all 56-card availability in real-time. Is it possible? is opencv the solution? i have no clue implementing it on my code :/

Program starts running, waiting for cards to be shown. it only recognizes cards on exact same size and resolution. program stops when reading 'reset.png' image.

Below there's code and screenshots to test:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import pyautogui

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Available Cards Playing")

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(14):
            tableCard = 'c%d%d' % (i, j) # building GUI table
            photo = PhotoImage(file='card_table/'+tableCard+'.gif')
            l = Label(image=photo)
            l.image=photo
            l.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
    root.attributes("-topmost", True) # window always on top
    root.attributes("-toolwindow", 1) # window no minimize
    loop = 0
    while loop < 1: # program is running infinitelly till we close the window
        resetTable = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('cards/reset.png')
        if resetTable is None:
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(14):
                        sCard = 's%d%d' % (i, j) # 56 cards one-by-one are being scanned
                        checkCard = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('cards/'+sCard+'.png')
                        if type(checkCard) == tuple: # checking if card was founded, then disable it on GUI
                                shadow = PhotoImage(file='card_table/dc%d%d.gif' % (i, j))
                                l = Label(image=shadow)
                                l.image=shadow
                                l.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
                                root.update()

        elif type(resetTable) == tuple: # if reset button is scanned, GUI resets 
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(14):
                    #
                    tableCard = 'c%d%d' % (i, j)
                    photo = PhotoImage(file='card_table/' + tableCard + '.gif')
                    l = Label(image=photo)
                    l.image = photo
                    l.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
                    root.update()
    root.mainloop()
```

[this is the gui interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xmiP.png) which u can use to test functionality

here's a temporary link of the project with .py and all images (173kb)
[zip](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/dc3d5c4f7866599aeb5ac1a332282e5520160516004604/5d73c8) so that you can try its functionality

Thanx in advance
Gio!

Comment: Well, if the cards are rendered that mean that the prosses know who they are, or is it rendered by a 3rd party prosses ?

Comment: the process renders desktop every millisec for the cards. but the scanning one-by-one makes it pretty slow. i would like to make it multi scan several cards at least *lets say at least every color simultaneously. but it doesnt. i want to multiscan-multitask. hope i helped you. you can try the app with given screenshots uploaded.